# How do I reuse release and environment variables in other existing release definitions in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2018 I have a list of Release definitions which should share the same variables. These variables consists of Release and Environment variables. For one release definition all the required release and environment variables are defined already.

However, I didn't find a way to easily reuse the defined variables in other existing release definitions in TFS 2018. Is there a way to do this?

**Creating variable groups is not an efficient option since defining multiple variable names in that group is not possible**

[image: Screenshot of Variables tab in one release definition. In the Scope section it is visible that there are release and environment variables]

**Example of defining the same variable name multiple times with different values and different scopes in a specific release definition. This is what I want also in a shared group:**

[image: Example of defining the same variable name multiple times with different values and different scopes in a specific release definition. This is what I want also in a shared group]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create variable groups for shared variables and link them to the releases and/or environments as appropriate.

Comment: I am aware of Variable groups, but it is not possible to define the same variable name multiple times in that group. This will not be an efficient solution.

Comment: You can't define the same variable name multiple times at **any** scope, though. Even if you could, the variables would overwrite one another. I don't understand the problem. Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: It IS possible on a specific release definition in the Variables tab to define a variable name multiple times, with different values and different **scopes**, however this is not possible in your suggested variable group. Otherwise I have to create multipe variable groups.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Variable group behavior is consistent with the behavior of variables in general. You can link a single variable group across different scopes.

Comment: I can link a single variable group across different scopes, however in my case the values are different for each scope. in the example variable name envId can only have 1 value. That means that I have to create an extra variable group to define variable envId with a different value.

Comment: @ajalalat Right. I don't understand how that differs from defining the same variable with a different value in a different scope. You create a variable group for each environment that needs different values. It's the same thing as defining variables at different scopes with different values, except you can reuse variable groups across releases.